# Error in WebControl Generation ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I got My All the Cotrols disappeared with Error

Error Creating Control
[controlid]
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM componenent.

Does Any one have ideas for this error?

I am working in Visual Studio 2010
OS :Windows7

this error has been genereated automatically when i started the project today.
Thanks
-Jadeja

Comment: The Application is executing properly, error is in design mode, no control display, even i can not drag any new components from toolbox, os is win-7 64 bit

Comment: After Some googlig i Founded the Solution  like

Delete cache  from Programfiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\  folder
And Restart the Studio, solved my Error